# Can someone help me with this pattern

Tags: vb.net

I can't figure out this simple(?) pattern in vb.net.

So the problem is this: I have 4 arrays of integers, 2 of them are from 0 to 29, and the last 2 are from 0 to 9. Now I am trying to make the pattern look like this:

[image]

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Clarify the question and, if it is homework, clearly say that.

Comment: So your homework is due today?

Comment: No it's not my homework because I'm on summer vacation :) but I'm trying to create a file name parses and files are named like 0|0|0|1, 0|0|0|2, 0|0|0|3 .... 0|0|1|0 ..... 0|0|1|9 .... 0|29|0|9

if it makes more sense like this the variables are A, B, C and D
the file name is like ABCD

Comment: You should post the code that you have, so that we have a better chance of understanding. So far, I can't tell what you've got for sure, and I can't tell what you're expecting to get back either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple LINQ-query should give you the expected result.

```
Dim big1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).ToArray()
Dim big2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).ToArray()
Dim small1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray()
Dim small2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray()

Dim result = From b1 in big1
             From b2 in big2
             From s1 in small1
             From s2 in small2
             Select New With {b1, b2, s1, s2}
```

[image]

**...**

[image]

It uses the [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) function:

> **Enumerable.SelectMany**
>
> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.